# Run sh script in Tcl foreach loop

Tags: bash, foreach, tcl

I have a simple bash script, test.sh, that takes four arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
echo "3: $3"
echo "4: $4"
```

I try to call this from a Tcl script, test.tcl

```
exec bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4

foreach i {1 2 3} {
    exec bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
}
```

The first call to the script outputs as I expect it to, but the calls from the foreach loop never seem to do anything. In fact, the `exec` command can be replaced with `exec ls` to make things even simpler; the call outside the loop works fine but the one from inside the loop doesn't do anything.

EDIT
As pointed out in the comments, it's probably important to mention I am using a Tcl console that is built into a software package (VMD, visual molecular dynamics). From that terminal interface, I call these scripts "interactively," and see output on the terminal from the `exec` outside the loop, but not from the one inside the loop.

My work is on hold because of this, any ideas?

Comment: Since this could be reproduced by just using `ls`, you could probably just `ls` in your question.

Comment: You are running the shell command and then discarding the output. Try `puts [exec bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4]`. This is true for the exec inside and outside the loop. So it is unclear to me why you claim that it works outside the loop, unless you run the commands interactively.

Comment: I'm a bit new to tcl. I've seen people using this `-c` option and doing things with `eval` and whatnot in the context of calling bash scripts from tcl scripts. I was hoping someone's answer would implicitly demystify some of that as well. I hope this is an appropriate way to ask a question here?

Comment: @SchelteBron I believe I am running them "interactively." I'm using a software package called VMD (Visual Molecular Dynamics) which has a tcl console built into it. From that tcl console, I call these scripts. This is actually the only way I know how to use tcl. Is this somehow the source of my confusion?

If so, any ideas why it might output the results to the console when called outside the loop but not when called inside the loop?

Comment: Running commands interactively will print the result without extra work from you. But when running commands inside a foreach loop, you just get the result of the foreach command, which has been defined to be the empty string. If you use lmap instead of foreach (assuming a recent enough Tcl version), you get a list of the return values of the last command in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent "issue" stems from trying to run these scripts "interactively." If I modify the bash script as

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1: $1" > $5
echo "2: $2" >>$5
echo "3: $3" >>$5
echo "4: $4" >>$5
```

and the tcl script as

```
exec bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 file1.txt

foreach i {1 2 3} {
    exec bash test.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 file2.txt
}
```

I see both files, `file{1,2}.txt`, created properly. So it automatically prints to the terminal interface when the script is called outside the loop but not when called inside. This is explained more in the comments above.

Comment: Interactive use of Tcl prints the result of each executed command (if it is not the empty string) after the command returns. The result of `exec` is whatever was written to stdout by the subprocess, but the result of `foreach` is the empty string. If you want to _always_ print out from the subprocess script, send the output to `/dev/tty`.